# IntelliJ with gradle gives inconsistency in compilation

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, compilation, consistency

I'm writing Minecraft Plugin using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with gradle. I have added  dependency `org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.13.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT` as `compileOnly`. During development, I noticed that gradle compiles my code in different way than IntelliJ does. For example, IntelliJ was unable to accept `addPassenger` on `Boat`, but gradle compiled it. In the opposite way, if I changed it into `setPassenger`, IntelliJ didn't mark it as error, but gradle failed to compile. I tried to invalidate caches, reimport, clean, even remove `%userprofile%\.gradle` directory, nothing helped. As a POC I changed `compileOnly` to `compile` and it worked well, IntelliJ and gradle compilation results were consistent. What's the reason?

Comment: Do you have https://i.imgur.com/AmWjMZR.png option enabled? If the dependencies are different in Gradle and in the IDE, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have such options enables as in your screenshot. Where can I check IDE dependencies? Gradle ones appears when I execute `gradle dependencies`

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies

Comment: Make sure the codebase IDEA works on and the codebase Gradle works on are actually identical. In Eclipse for example, there is a `gradle` folder and Eclipse needs to update buildship, otherwise Gradle tasks will use an outdated codebase, even though calling `gradlew` will compile an up-2-date codebase. I don't remember how the Gradle integration worked in IDEA, but make a 100% sure you are actually on the same codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution (and forgot about this question).

I had been using multiple dependencies, and one load another with older version that I loaded implicitly in my `build.gradle`. However, they weren't exactly the same dependencies, but parallel ones. So gradle could not choose higher version of one dependency. Solution was to exclude this one explicitly loaded dependency and everything worked well.

Before:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-bukkit:7.0.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.spigotmc', name:'spigot-api', version: '1.15.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

After:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly('com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-bukkit:7.0.1') {
        exclude `org.bukkit:bukkit:1.15.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT`
    }
    compileOnly group: 'org.spigotmc', name:'spigot-api', version: '1.15.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```